# Make Ubuntu compatible with Arabic language

Tags: 14.04, customization, arabic

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I want to make Ubuntu compatible with Arabic language Can you help me please

Comment: Search for Text Entry in dash. After it opened, choose Arabic as your preferred language.

Comment: **Also:** Check out other questions (and answers) with **arabic** tag, by right-clicking on tag (above).

Answer (score 6):

1. اذهب إلى (Go to)

   [image]
2. افتح (Open)

   [image]
3. اضغط على علامة الزائد لإضافة لغة (Click on plus sign to add a language)

   [image]
4. سوف تظهر لك اللغات (List of languages will show up)

   [image]
5. إذا أضفت اللغة العربية سوف تجدها في القائمة الرئيسية الفوقية (If you added Arabic, you find it on the upper list)

   [image]
6. إن لم تجد اللغة العربية في المرحلة الرابعة (If you couldn't find it in step 4)

   [image]

   [image]

ثم (Done)

[image]

ثم عد إلى المرحلة رقم 2 (Then go back to step 2)

Comment: Nice detailed answer. Ask Ubuntu language is English, so at least provide translation when you are obliged to use a different language. btw OP asked in English so should your answer!

Comment: Old post and comment. But this **is** useful in both languages. Although I use Ubuntu in English, it helps to see instructions in both languages. The author is simply going out of his way to be more helpful.